# A question about the math definition of predecessor

Tags: elementary-set-theory, notation, peano-axioms

> Every natural number, with the exception of $0$, has a predecessor: $\mathbb{N}^{+} = \mathbb{N} \backslash  \{0\}$

I know what predecessor means but can't understand this equation.

Comment: It is defining $\mathbb{N}^{+}$ to be the set of all natural numbers except $0$

Comment: @Meijke thanks, but still confusing about the meaning of operator $=$ here.

Comment: The symbol "\" (setminus) means ["subtraction"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Set_(mathematics)#Complements) or relative compleent: "the relative complement of $B$ in $A$ (also called the set-theoretic difference of $A$ and $B$), denoted by $A \setminus B$, is the set of all elements that are members of $A$ but not members of $B$."

Comment: $\mathbb N^+$ is being defined as all the natural numbers that do have a predecessor.  This set is all of the natural numbers except $0$.  That notation $\mathbb N \setminus \{0\}$ means all the natural numbers except $0$.  ($A\setminus B$ means all the elements of $A$ that are not in $B$.)  so this equation is *literally* saying "All the natural number with predecessors ($\mathbb N^+$) is all the natural numbers with the exception of $0$ ($\mathbb N\setminus \{0\}$).

Comment: @MauroALLEGRANZA fleablood Thanks, you have addressed my confusions!